# Simulating covariance and contravariance in templates with polymorphic parameters using reinterpret_cast and static_cast?

Tags: c++, templates, polymorphism, c++14, reinterpret-cast

Let's say I have a simple polymorphic inheritance:

```
struct Base
{
    virtual void exec() { std::cout << "base" << std::endl; }
    virtual ~Base() { }
};

struct Derived1 : public Base
{
    void exec() override { std::cout << "derived1" <<std::endl; }
};

struct Derived2 : public Base
{
    void exec() override { std::cout << "derived2" << std::endl; }
};
```

And I also have a template `Wrapper` class that stores some generic data:

```
template<typename T> struct Wrapper : public T
{
    bool b{true};     
};
```

Can I safely convert from `Wrapper<Derived1>` to `Base` and from `Base` to `Wrapper<Derived1>` using the following casts?

```
template<typename T> auto& asWrapper(T& mX) 
{ 
    return static_cast<Wrapper<T>&>(mX); 
}

template<typename T, typename TWrapper> auto& asT(TWrapper& mX) 
{ 
    return reinterpret_cast<T&>(mX); 
}
```

Example that seems to work:

```
int main()
{
    auto d1 = std::make_unique<Wrapper<Derived1>>();
    auto d2 = std::make_unique<Wrapper<Derived2>>();

    Base* bd1 = d1.get();
    Base* bd2 = d2.get();

    bd1->exec();
    bd2->exec();

    auto& bl1 = asWrapper(*bd1);
    auto& bl2 = asWrapper(*bd2);

    std::cout << bl1.b << " " << bl2.b << std::endl;
    bl1.b = false;
    std::cout << bl1.b << " " << bl2.b << std::endl;
    bl2.b = false;
    std::cout << bl1.b << " " << bl2.b << std::endl;

    asT<Derived1>(bl1).exec();
    asT<Derived2>(bl2).exec();

    return 0;
}
```

Executable example: http://ideone.com/MRy9Hy

---

It seems to work, but I'm not convinced of the safety of this approach. Is it standard-compliant? Could it cause undefined behavior?

Comment: the first static cast gives you a `Wrapper<Base>` not `Wrapper<DerivedX>` - which I'd imagine is *not safe* (in this simple example, you won't get any side effects from slicing, however if `DerivedX` has some state, then I'd say this is UB)... The second is odd... what's wrong with `dynamic_cast`?

Comment: @Nim: I tried the same code with some simple state (storing a `float` in `Derived1` and a string in `Derived2`, and printing them in `exec()`). It still seems to work correctly. I don't want to use `dynamic_cast` as it can have runtime overhead, and I acutally know the types of the objects inside `Wrapper` when I write the code. If you think that this is unsafe, is there any way I can obtain the same results without having to touch `Base`, `Derived1` and `Derived2`?

Comment: I've added one `std::string` to the `Derived1` and `Derived2` classes and the program gives me wrong results when printing `b`.

Comment: BTW those `public` are unnecessary.

Comment: "as it can have runtime overhead" [Premature optimization is the root of all evil](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?PrematureOptimization).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### aswrapper

N4140 [expr.static.cast]/2:

> An lvalue of type “*cv1* `B`,” where `B` is a class type, can be cast to type “reference to *cv2* `D`,” where `D` is a class derived (Clause 10) from `B`, if a valid standard conversion from “pointer to `D`” to “pointer to `B`” exists (4.10), *cv2* is the same cv-qualification as, or greater cv-qualification than, *cv1*, and `B` is neither a virtual base class of `D` nor a base class of a virtual base class of `D`. The result has type “*cv2* `D`.” An xvalue of type “*cv1* `B`” may be cast to type “rvalue reference to *cv2* `D`” with the same constraints as for an lvalue of type “*cv1* `B`.” If the object of type “*cv1* `B`” is actually a subobject of an object of type `D`, the result refers to the enclosing object of type `D`. Otherwise, the behavior is undefined.

So your function `aswrapper` has defined behavior only if the `T&` passed to it actually refers to a `T` base object of a `Wrapper<T>`. Both calls in the example program convert a `Base&` to `Wrapper<Base>&`, but neither argument is actually a base object of a `Wrapper<Base>&`, so the resulting behavior is undefined.

### asT

[expr.reinterpret.cast]:

> ...
>
> 7 An object pointer can be explicitly converted to an object pointer of a different type. When a prvalue `v` of object pointer type is converted to the object pointer type “pointer to *cv* `T`”, the result is `static_cast<cv T*>(static_cast<cv void*>(v))`. Converting a prvalue of type “pointer to `T1`” to the type “pointer to `T2`” (where `T1` and `T2` are object types and where the alignment requirements of `T2` are no stricter than those of `T1`) and back to its original type yields the original pointer value.
>
> ...
>
> 11 A glvalue expression of type `T1` can be cast to the type “reference to `T2`” if an expression of type “pointer to `T1`” can be explicitly converted to the type “pointer to `T2`” using a `reinterpret_cast`. The result refers
>   to the same object as the source glvalue, but with the specified type. [ Note: That is, for lvalues, a reference cast `reinterpret_cast<T&>(x)` has the same effect as the conversion `*reinterpret_cast<T*>(&x)` with the built-in `&` and `*` operators (and similarly for `reinterpret_cast<T&&>(x)`). —end note ] No temporary is created, no copy is made, and constructors (12.1) or conversion functions (12.3) are not called.

so `asT<T>(WrapperT& foo)` is equivalent to `*reinterpret_cast<T*>(&foo)` which is equivalent to `*static_cast<T*>(static_cast<void*>(&foo))`. A pointer to `Wrapper<Base>` can of course be cast to `void*` per [expr.static.cast]/4:

> An expression `e` can be explicitly converted to a type `T` using a `static_cast` of the form `static_cast<T>(e)` if the declaration `T t(e);` is well-formed, for some invented temporary variable `t` (8.5). The effect of such an explicit conversion is the same as performing the declaration and initialization and then using the temporary variable as the result of the conversion. The expression `e` is used as a glvalue if and only if the initialization uses it as a glvalue.

since any pointer type implicitly converts to `void*` per [conv.ptr]/2:

> A prvalue of type “pointer to *cv* `T`,” where `T` is an object type, can be converted to a prvalue of type “pointer to *cv* `void`”. The result of converting a non-null pointer value of a pointer to object type to a “pointer to
>   *cv* `void`” represents the address of the same byte in memory as the original pointer value. The null pointer value is converted to the null pointer value of the destination type.

That `void*` can be converted to any object pointer type via [expr.static.cast]/13:

> A prvalue of type “pointer to *cv1* `void`” can be converted to a prvalue of type “pointer to *cv*2 `T`,” where `T` is an object type and *cv2* is the same cv-qualification as, or greater cv-qualification than, *cv1*. The null pointer
>   value is converted to the null pointer value of the destination type. If the original pointer value represents the address `A` of a byte in memory and `A` satisfies the alignment requirement of `T`, then the resulting pointer
>   value represents the same address as the original pointer value, that is, `A`. The result of any other such pointer conversion is unspecified. A value of type pointer to object converted to “pointer to *cv* `void`” and back, possibly with different cv-qualification, shall have its original value.

Given the above `asT` is well-formed - which you knew already since the compiler didn't diagnose it. However, the two calls in the example program have unspecified behavior since the alignment of `Wrapper<Base>` may not satisfy the alignment requirement of `Derived1` or `Derived2`. Even if the alignment requirement *was* satisfied, the calls to `exec` most likely fall afoul of the strict aliasing restrictions in 3.10/10 since you are treating what is presumably the object representation of a `Wrapper<Base>` as if it were a `Derived`.

Written with `reinterpret_cast` as it is, `asT<Base>(Wrapper<Base>&)` even has undefined behavior. Certainly the alignment requirement is satisfied since `Wrapper<Base>` derives from `Base`, but actually using the returned glvalue to access memory only has defined behavior if the address of a `Wrapper<Base>` is the same as the address of its `Base` subobject. This would be the case if `Wrapper<Base>` were standard-layout, but otherwise object layouts are unspecified.

### Summary

The program has several occurrences of undefined behavior. The appearance of working correctly is an artifact of the object layouts chosen by the implementation.